# Python format and print data in specific order from nested List

Tags: python, list

I have a list that looks like this:

```
[(6, {3: 3, 4: 3, 7: 2, 1: 3, 11: 2}), 
(1, {7: 3, 9: 2, 11: 4, 3: 2, 6: 3, 4: 3, 12: 2}), 
(4, {3: 2, 7: 3, 6: 3, 1: 3, 11: 2, 12: 3}), (2, {9: 4, 8: 2, 10: 2, 5: 2})
```

and I need to format it and print it so it looks like this:

```
 6:Might(1,3,4,7,11) 
 1:Might(4,6,7) Probably(11)
 4:Might(1,3,6,11,12) 
13:
```

I have tried this:

```
for item in connect_out:
name = item[0]
pair_dict = item[1]
might = []
probably = []
for key, value in pair_dict.items():
    if value > 3:
        probably.append(str(value))
    else:
        might.append(str(value))
might = sorted(might)
probably = sorted(probably)
print("%s:Might(%s) Probably(%s)" % (name, ','.join(might),','(probably)) )
```

and I got this:

```
    6:Might(2,2,3,3,3) Probably()
    1:Might(2,2,2,3,3,3) Probably(4)
    4:Might(2,2,3,3,3,3) Probably()
   13:Might() Probably()
```

If there is nothing in the might or probably list neither title should print. I put some print statements in and it looks like it is putting the number after the colon in the might list instead of the one before it.

Comment: Maybe it would be clearer what the problem is if you showed what you have tried already and what went wrong.

Comment: On SO, you have to attempt to code it yourself and post the code you tried and explain what's not working about it.

Comment: You're trying to handle json. That's a list of tuples, where the second element in the tuple is a dict. Please look at all the existing questions and answers on SO on that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do some preprocessing before sending this off to `print()`
You can start with something like this:

```
values = [(6, {3: 3, 4: 3, 7: 2, 1: 3, 11: 2}), 
(1, {7: 3, 9: 2, 11: 4, 3: 2, 6: 3, 4: 3, 12: 2}), 
(4, {3: 2, 7: 3, 6: 3, 1: 3, 11: 2, 12: 3}), (2, {9: 4, 8: 2, 10: 2, 5: 2})]
for item in values:
    name = item[0]
    pair_dict = item[1]
    might = []
    probably = []
    for key, value in pair_dict.items():
        if value > 3:
            probably.append(value)
        else:
            might.append(value)
    might = sorted(might)
    probably = sorted(probably)
    print("%s:Might(%s) Probably(%s)" % (name, ','.join(might), ','.join(probably))
```

EDIT: After tinkering a bit and better understanding your requirements, try this on for size:

```
values = [(6, {3: 3, 4: 3, 7: 2, 1: 3, 11: 2}), 
(1, {7: 3, 9: 2, 11: 4, 3: 2, 6: 3, 4: 3, 12: 2}), 
(4, {3: 2, 7: 3, 6: 3, 1: 3, 11: 2, 12: 3}), (2, {9: 4, 8: 2, 10: 2, 5: 2})]
for item in values:
    name = item[0]
    pair_dict = item[1]
    might = []
    probably = []
    for key, value in pair_dict.items():
        if value > 3:
            probably.append(value)
        else:
            might.append(value)
    might = [str(i) for i in sorted(might)]
    probably = [str(i) for i in sorted(probably)]
    mightstr = "" if len(might) == 0 else "Might(%s) " % ','.join(might)
    probablystr = "" if len(probably) == 0 else "Probably(%s)" %  ','.join(probably)
    print("%s:%s%s" % (name, mightstr, probablystr))
```

Comment: It game me the error sequence item 0: expected string,found so I converted the value to str when I append  but the output is incorrect. I got this                                                                                                                                              6:Might(2,2,3,3,3) Probably()                                                                                                                                                          
1:Might(2,2,2,3,3,3) Probably(4 )

Comment: It also prints probably and might when there is nothing there - like this 10:Might(2,2,2,3,3) Probably() and this 13:Might() Probably() s/b                                    10:Might(#,#,#) and nothing after it if there is no probably and 13 should just be this              13:    with no probably or might with empty parentheses.